# How to get List of similar elements using javascriptexecutor using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2, browser-automation, javascript

I want to get list of similar element into arraylist using javascriptexecutor. However able to store only single element using javascriptexecutor.
Here is my code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Objectload=js.executeScript("document.evaluate(\"//article/footer/div[1]/h3/text()[2]\",document,null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return stringValue;");
```

using this i found only single locator however other element in similar kind of xpath `"//article/footer/div[1]/h3/text()[2]\"` also exist.
Can you plz help me to resolve this..

Comment: Can you add the html code of the elements (you want to interact with)  to your question

Comment: @the_code Please check Screencast for html code https://www.screencast.com/t/RiDiSyBD7by

Comment: URL of the application : http://carrier.veritread.com/search and i want to retrive xpath for that : https://www.screencast.com/t/zPt3NhPJ

Answer (score 2):

List of similar elements can be found by `JavascriptExecutor` using selenium webdriver in following way:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

    List<WebElement> eles = (List<WebElement>) js.executeScript("var results = new Array();"
            + "var element = document.evaluate(\"//h3[@class='location']\", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);"
            + "for ( var i = 0 ; i < element.snapshotLength ; i++ )"
            + "{"
            +    "results.push(element.snapshotItem(i));"
            + "}"
            + "return results;","");
```

In the above code it is necessary that `XpathResult` is of `SNAPSHOT` type.

Through the above list we would get all the elements with `h3` tag having `class='location'`. From then on we can convert those elements into Strings.

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement e : eles)
{
  strings.add(e.getText());
}
```

Following links have been helpful:

1. findElementsByXpath in Javascript: https://gist.github.com/tit/4695818
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303869/how-to-use-document-evaluate-to-get-the-list-of-elements-pointed-by-xpath